# mingw g++ cant see sdl-config

Tags: c++, windows, linux, unix, mingw

[image: sceenshot]

All works good if I insert sdl-config output manually.

How to fix this bug?

```
g++ -O3 -c 'sdl-config --cflags' test.cpp
g++.exe: sdl-config --cflags: no such dile or directory
```

Comment: Are you cross-compiling? Are you running under linux/cygwin/MSYS bash?

Comment: I dont know what is "cross compiling"

Comment: I have succesfully installed:

Comment: 3) libjpeg libpng giflib libtiff from sources

Comment: my g++ dont work correctly - it is a fact

Comment: more see here https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3084661&group_id=2435&atid=102435

Comment: @puchu, please read the faq. SO is no discussion forum, use answers to answer the question, use comments to comment and edit the question if you forgot to include something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh...
I mixed up ` and ' !!!!!

now all works...

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that sh dont work correctly!

I make sh script mmake:

```
#!/bin/sh
g++ -O3 -c `sdl-config --cflags` test.cpp
g++ -O3 -o test test.o `sdl-config --libs` -lSDL_image
```

and all work great!

why it dont work at main console window???